# Restore Specific Postgres table from outside Docker container using .sql file

Tags: postgresql, devops, database-restore, pg-restore

I can able to take dump of specific table outside the container  by the below command,

```
docker exec -i postgres /bin/bash -c "pg_dump -U <user_name> -d <db_name> -t 'public.\"<table_name>\"' " > <file_name>.sql
```

Tried multiple ways, but I'm unable to restore the specific postgres table from outside the container.
I've used the below command, please help me with this.

```
docker exec -i postgres /bin/bash -c "pg_restore -U <user_name> -d <db_name> -t 'public.\"<table_name>\"' " > <file_name>.sql
```

Comment: Well, what happened?

Comment: The above command to restore a specific table in the ubuntu server isn't correct.